# Token separator in Page Title

Tags: tokens, 7

I'm using the Meta Tags module to pretty up my page titles using tokens.  I want to display the taxonomy term parents in the page title, with separators.  It's working, except I need it to also END with a separator.  Though if no parent exists, I don't want the separator, obviously.

What I have so far:

```
[term:parents:join:&nbsp;-&nbsp;][term:name] | [site:name]
```

But I want a dash (or pipe, or something besides a space) right before the term:name token for when there is a parent.  But this:

```
[term:parents:join:&nbsp;-&nbsp;] - [term:name] | [site:name]
```

Results in all page titles without parents to start with the dash.  Any ideas?

Comment: See this other DAstackexchange thread with my un-approved answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24580/3279. When you have conditional things like this you tread the line of not having just a "token" anymore. So you have to find a way to alter this using code. drupal_set_title() is 1 way. Or messing with $vars['head_title'] in hook_preprocess_html() is another way.

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid it'd be complicated. I'll work on that, it does seem to be the answer. For now, I'm putting a single space - not the prettiest but it'll get me through today.  Thanks!